# How do I push an image below the text and write a caption next to the picture?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to push the iphone phone image below the text. Next, I want to add text next to the image. I have tried relative and absolute positioning but not sure what type of padding to use.

I have tried relative and absolute positioning but not sure how many pixels of padding to use.

```
<div class="very-bottom-half">
        <img class = "second-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="duh-a-logo">
        <img class = "phone" src = "images/phone.png" alt = "phone-home">
        <p>215-900-2565</p>
</div>


.phone {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
```

I expect the phone image to go below the text and then I expect to have text written next to the image.

Comment: where is the text in the snippet above?

Comment: I just added in the text (<p></p>) below.

Comment: so you want the text to next to the image in the same line?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` to get the elements side by side in one.

```css
.very-bottom-half {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="very-bottom-half">
  <img class="second-logo" src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper-big.jpg" alt="duh-a-logo">
  <img class="phone" src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper-big.jpg" alt="phone-home">
  <p>215-900-2565</p>
</div>
```